# SpriteKit applyImpulse crash

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I try to use applyImpulse on my node app crashes and I receive this: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`
Here is code:

```
    self.character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
    self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerCat
    self.character.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ObstaclesCat
    self.character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.mass = 5
    self.character.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
    self.character.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
```

And my applyImpulse:
    `character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0,100))`
I have tried a few things and I now that the issue is that size of SKPhysicsBody is nil, but why it is? The same is even if I try to manually set size.

Comment: You character is probably nil.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are trying to apply an action or physics onto a non-existant node which is empty and thus it crashes.

Comment: I have checked and it's nil only when I call it from TouchesBegan function. It's not nil if I call it from function where I create it(but it's also a property).

Comment: if it's nil in `touchesBegan`, it means you are not referring to the correct variable or are not referring to it. Without code to refer to, I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1.0)

        self.character.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * 0.5)

        self.addChild(self.character)
        self.character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
        self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
//        self.character.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.PlayerCat
//        self.character.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ObstaclesCat
        self.character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.character.physicsBody?.mass = 5
        self.character.physicsBody?.friction = 0.5
        self.character.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        self.character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1000))

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'let character' to 'var character'. And no need to add 'self' before the lines.